# How to unlock a thread within lock brackets

Tags: c#, c++, multithreading

I am trying to convert this C++ code into a C#:

```
do{
    if (Node->NextNode == NULL) WaitForSingleObject(pThis->_Event, INFINITE);
    _critSect.Lock();
    if (Node->NextNode == NULL && !bRunning ) 
    {
        _critSect.Unlock(); // can explicitly unlock here
        break;
    }
    _critSect.Unlock();
}while (Node->NextNode == NULL);
```

In C++, I can explicitly unlock the thread, but C# only has a bracket. How can I add the "unlock" function in the code below before breaking?

```
do{
   if (Node->NextNode == null) DataQueueEvent.WaitOne();
   lock (thisLock)
   {
      if (Node->NextNode == null && !bRunning)
      // need to unlock here!!!                      
      break;
   }
} while (Node->NextNode == null);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's simply unnecessary.  in C# the `lock` statement translates into a `try`/`finally`, so the lock will be released whenever you exit the block *regardless of how you exit the block*, so there's no need to explicitly release the lock when you exit using the `break` path.

Comment: and in fact the c++ code is really bad. It should have wrapped the critsect in a class so that it will get released on scope exit too

Comment: Thank you. That was supposed to be obvious. )

Answer (score 2):

In additon to what servy  stated and if you want to see how this is done under the hood take a look  at  this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd289498(v=vs.110).aspx)

the lock statement will be converted once compiled to

```
bool acquiredLock = false;
try
{
    Monitor.Enter(lockObject, ref acquiredLock);

    // Code that accesses resources that are protected by the lock.

}
finally
{
    if (acquiredLock)
    {
        Monitor.Exit(lockObject);
    }
}
```